# Не понимаю почему не работает запрос? nodejs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Хочу добавить полученые регионы из баны данных в выподающее меню, но не очень понимаю почему не могут нормально обработать запрос,
по идее в функции `showRegions` в main.js должен быть список регионов.

это у меня в файле main.js

```
function showRegions(data) {
    if (document.querySelector(".dropdown-menu")) {
        console.log(data)
    }
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    main()
});

getText = async function (url, callback) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            console.log(request.responseText)
            callback(request.responseText);
        }
    };
    console.log("передал гет")
    request.open("GET", url);
    request.send();
}
function main(){
    getText('/getAllRegions', showRegions);

}
```

потом по логике я должен обработать этот запрос

обрабатываю в app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
const db_funcs = require("./db/db_func.js")

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', (req, res, next)=>{
  console.log("рендерим индекс")
  res.render("index")
})

app.get('/getAllRegions', (req, res, next)=>{
  console.log("гет запрос пришел")
  let result = db_funcs.getRegions()
  console.log(result)
  // res.send(data)

})
```

и в самом файлике db_funcs.js, где лежат запросы к базе данных:

```
async function getRegions() {
    const response = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const query = "SELECT stops.zone_name FROM stops GROUP BY zone_name;"
    connection.query(query, (err, results) => {
        if(err) reject(new Error(err.message));
            // console.log(results)
            resolve(results);
            // return results;
        });
        return response
    })
};
```

upd 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### В чём проблема?

Проблема в методе `getRegions`. Данные из него не возвращаются из-за того что создаваемый `Promise` не возвращается из функции.

Если убрать запрос то код выглядит так:

```js
async function getRegions() {
    // просто константа с которой больше ничего не происходит
    const response = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Ничего по сути не делает т.к. возврат идёт не из getRegions
        // а из коллбека внутри Promise
        return response
    })
};
```

#### Исправить можно так

db_funcs.js:

```js
// Убрали async, т.к. он не нужен
function getRegions() {
    // Сразу возвращаем Promise. не складываем в переменную
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const query = "SELECT stops.zone_name FROM stops GROUP BY zone_name;"
        connection.query(query, (err, results) => {
            if (err) reject(new Error(err.message));
            // console.log(results)
            resolve(results);
            // return results;
        });
    })
};
```

app.js:

```js
// Вот тут async нужен что бы дождаться ответа от getRegions
app.get('/getAllRegions', async (req, res, next)=>{
  console.log("гет запрос пришел")
  // Ждём getRegions при поможи await 
  let result = await db_funcs.getRegions()
  console.log(result)
  // res.send(data)

})
```

Comment: видимо  это были не все мои ошибки, ибо в app.js у меня не содержится ответа из db_func.js

Comment: console.log("гет запрос пришел"), даже не отрабатывает в app.js

Comment: Тогда стоит посмотреть код до `app.get('/getAllRegions', ...)` потому что часть с отправкой запроса на стороне браузера работает

Comment: я апдтейтнул, не мог бы взглянуть?

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `app.use` на `app.get`. Либо в `app.use` нужно добавить проверку на url и вызывать `next()` если дальше подразумеваются другие методы